# Null reference exception on generic collection query

Tags: c#, exception, find, nullreferenceexception, generic-collections

I was getting a null reference exception on the following line

```
VATinsrcommision  = _input_articletranstax
    .ARTEAMNTTRANTAX
    .Find(p => 
         p.TAXTYPECDE == TaxType.VAT_GST.GetStringValue())
    .TAXAMT;
```

So I wrote this :

```
var VAT = _input_articletranstax
    .ARTEAMNTTRANTAX
    .Find(p => 
         p.TAXTYPECDE == TaxType.VAT_GST.GetStringValue());

if (VAT != null)
  VATinsrcommision = VAT.TAXAMT;
```

I want to know how can I do this in a better way

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that. You're now using a null check for more defensive code, that's how it should be.

Comment: This is the best way.

Comment: If it were me (and I'm nit-picking), I'd maybe just evaluate `VATinsrcommision`) without the involvement of another 'temporary' variable (`VAT`). I'm assuming you want to do something with `VATinsrcommision` but according to this bit of code it could still be null, so just test it later on when it's needed as you'll have to anyway.

Comment: Like in LINQ query we can write like this:
(from o in m_SelectedPayabes 
                         where o != null
                         select o.PBLE.PAYABLEID).Contains(payable.PBLE.PAYABLEID)
So I want to know can we something like this for generic collection?

Comment: Possibly, yes, but how are we meant to know what types you're working with? Even with LINQ, you're going to end up with a value that's null or not. So you need to check for that. Which is what you're doing anyway. So I don't see what you want to improve on.

Comment: OK. thanks for help. Maybe this ok.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)